# Ler arquivos e colocar automaticamente na linha desejada;

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho vários arquivos em uma pasta: 01.PNG, 02.PNG, 05.PNG, alguns dos arquivos não tem (04.PNG, 03.PNG).

Qual seria a forma mais fácil de escrever um documento de texto onde cada nome de arquivo seria escrito no mesmo número de linha:

Assim:

```
01.PNG
02.PNG


05.PNG
```

NOTE QUE OS ARQUIVOS FALTANTES, as linhas foram apenas puladas!

Comment: Já tentou alguma coisa? Qual foi a dificuldade?

Comment: To procurando a linguagem mais fácil pra fazer isso. Como vou fazer no excel, comecei a procurar por la, mas aceito uma solução em python ou qualquer outra tbm! Sabe se tem como fazer pelo bash do windows?

Answer (score 1):

No C# eu utilizo o seguinte código para realizar a leitura dos arquivos, ordenados por data de criação:

```
using System.IO;

string path=@"C:\ExampleArquivos"; \\caminho onde estão os arquivos

var files = new DirectoryInfo(pathexportacao).GetFiles().OrderBy(x => x.CreationTime).ToList();
```

Após ler os arquivos, você pode realizar um foreach para salvar o nome em um txt.

```
string path=@"C:\Example\Example.txt";

foreach (var file in files)
        {  
            File.Create(path).Dispose();
            using(TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path))
            {
              tw.WriteLine(file.Name);
              tw.Close();
             }
        }
```

Comment: Vlw! muito obrigado

Comment: Fui realizar o teste somente hoje! Voce usa visual studio para programar em C#? Como sou novo posso ter feito algo errado mas pelo que me parece está sempre sobrescrevendo no arquivo de texto e assim quando abro o arquivo só tem uma linha escrita.

Comment: Tente concatenar então com \n, assim:
tw.WriteLine(file.Name + " \n");

Answer (score 0):

Como vc disse que vai utilizar o excel, recomendo desenvolver isso em VBA. Não vai fugir do conceito do seu problema e é uma linguagem com muito (muito mesmo) suporte das pessoas na internet.

Não programo em VBA, mas vc entendendo a base dele não terá segredo...

```
novo: arquivo
se > arquivo existe 
imprime: nome, quebra a linha
se > arquivo não existe
imprime: quebra linha, quebra linha
```